# Scrolling a Texture2D that is in a RawImage?

Tags: scroll, unity-game-engine, texture2d

Is this possible with Unity3D? ...

I have a `Texture2D` in a `RawImage` that is used to display on a UI `Canvas` and pixels are drawn into it with `SetPixel()` and then I want to scroll the `Texture2D` pixel by pixel. I don't want to use any material or fancy stuff as this code should be very efficient and lightweight. Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a wrapper class for `Texture2D` that adds API to better work with pixel manipulation tasks. It still all uses `GetPixels`/`SetPixels` since there isn't really much more API than that in Unity3D currently. But it's better than nothing. If anyone has a better method or suggestions it would be cool if you can share them.

Here's the class named Bitmap2D https://gist.github.com/hexagonstar/be39f847a4840c838500